# Crop video after upload in laravel

Tags: laravel, ffmpeg

I have a functionality to upload videos in laravel.
Now I have to crop the uploaded video first 20 seconds and need to save the cropped video into different directory.

I went through this package.

```
https://github.com/protonemedia/laravel-ffmpeg
```

I have installed the package. But not getting the code for crop. Can any one help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use FFMpeg;

// ...

public function handleVideoUpload(Request $request)
{
    $video = $request->file('video');

    // Generate a unique filename for the cropped video
    $croppedVideoPath = 'path/to/save/cropped/' . uniqid('cropped_video_') . '.mp4';

    // Crop the first 20 seconds of the video
    FFMpeg::open($video)
        ->crop(new \FFMpeg\Coordinate\TimeCode(0), new \FFMpeg\Coordinate\TimeCode(20))
        ->export()
        ->toDisk('public') // You can change the disk as needed
        ->inFormat(new \FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264)
        ->save($croppedVideoPath);

    // Now you can save the $croppedVideoPath to your database or perform any other actions

    // ...
}
```

Ensure that you have configured your filesystem disk properly in the config/filesystems.php file. You might want to use the public disk for storing the cropped videos.

```
'disks' => [
    // ...

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => public_path(),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

    // ...
]
```

,

Comment: Thankyou @Karl for the reply. I'll check and update to you.

Comment: Disk [videos] does not have a configured driver.", exception: "InvalidArgumentException"

Answer (score 0):

I have got another solution. I have run this command:

```
$video_path = storage_path('app/public/uploads/vide_Upload2_image/' . $single_video_details->uploaded_video);
$croppedVideoPath = storage_path('app/public/uploads/vide_Upload2_image/cropped_video.mp4');
   
$ffmpegCommand = "C:/FFmpeg/bin/ffmpeg -i " . $video_path . " -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:00:10 " . $croppedVideoPath;
$test = exec($ffmpegCommand);
```

And it works.

I have removed the package.